# Nginx match against variable

Tags: regex, nginx

I try to check based on the request URI and OIDC roles in HTTP header if the user has access to a specific directory.

Currently I use statically defined

```
server {
  location /tool/ {
    location /tool/abc/ {
      if ($http_x_auth_roles !~ '(^|,)MY_DEFINED_ROLE_FOR_abc(,|$)') {
        return 403;
      }
    }
    # and so on for every single tool
  }
}
```

I tried to switch to a generic variant but the matching does not work:

```
map $request_uri $expected_role {
  default         'DOES_NOT_MATCH';
  '~^/tool/(.+)/' 'MY_DEFINED_ROLE_FOR_$1';
}
server {
  location /tool/ {
    if ($http_x_auth_roles !~ $expected_role) {
      return 403;
    }
  }
}
```

I checked the content of `$expected_role` and it's showing exactly what I want, but it never matches. Is there some kind of work around to achieve what I want?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot specify a regular expression inside a variable.

Comment: @RichardSmith and is there something else which could be used as a work around?